# How to take correct entry from an array which has multiple entries with similar names -PHP

Tags: php, regex

I get data from a service regarding product details.the array for a one product is structured as follows with more data when i exploded CSV data and print_r one entry.

```
 [Product_name] => Product1
 [Manufacturer] => Manufacturer
 <<more elements>>
 [Image URL #1] => http://www.image1.jpg
 [Image Label #1] => PRODUCT_IMAGE
 [Image_info Label #1] => Marketing Image High Res
 [Image URL #2] => https://www.image2.jpg
 [Image Label #2] =>PRODUCT_IMAGE
 [Image_info Label #2] =>Mobile Image
 [Image URL #3] =>https://www.image3.jpg
 [Image Label #3] => PRODUCT_IMAGE
 [Image_info Label #3] => Marketing Image High Res
```

i need to take first image comes as PRODUCT IMAGE and Marketing Image High Res. this may not always Image URL #1. what would be the proper way to identify the correct URL to show?
can i use regex to get this done?

Here is a sample CSV

```
 Item ID,Brand Name,Manufacturer,Short Name,Long Name,Storage Temp From,Gross Weight,Gross Weight UOM,Net Weight,Net Weight UOM,Catch Weight,Height,Image URL #1,Image Label #1,Image_info Label #1,Image URL #2,Image Label #2,Image_info Label #2,Image URL #3,Image Label #3,Image_info Label #3,Image URL #4,Image Label #4,Image_info Label #4,Image URL #5,Image Label #5,Image_info Label #5
    2056434,CONTINENTAL MILLS VALUE,CONTINENTAL MILLS INC.,CM VALUE BTMK BISCUIT,CONTINENTAL MILLS VALUE BUTTERMILK BISCUIT,32,51.5,LBR,50,LBR,No,5,http:// example.com/Buttermilk_Biscuit.jpg,PRODUCT_IMAGE,Marketing Image High Res,https:// example.com/image2.jpg,PRODUCT_IMAGE,Sell Sheet / Mobile Image,https:// example.com/image3.jpg,PRODUCT_IMAGE,Marketing Image High Res,https:// example.com/image4.jpg,PRODUCT_IMAGE,Case Image,https:// example.com/image5.jpg,CHILD_NUTRITION_LABEL,Marketing Image High Res
    2056463,CONTINENTAL MILLS VALUE,CONTINENTAL MILLS INC.,CM VALUE BTMK BISCUIT,CONTINENTAL MILLS VALUE BUTTERMILK BISCUIT,32,51.5,LBR,50,LBR,No,5,http:// example.com/Buttermilk_Biscuit.jpg,PRODUCT_IMAGE,Marketing Image High Res,https:// example.com/image2.jpg,PRODUCT_IMAGE,Sell Sheet / Mobile Image,https:// example.com/image3.jpg,PRODUCT_IMAGE,Marketing Image High Res,https:// example.com/image4.jpg,PRODUCT_IMAGE,Case Image,https:// example.com/image5.jpg,CHILD_NUTRITION_LABEL,Marketing Image High Res
```

Comment: I think they read it, but can't find some code you tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @mickmackusa a good question and one which my original answer wasn't dependent on...

Comment: sorry for lateness i was trying @Nicks solution. i updated the question

Comment: @mickmackusa hope you find info you needed in question.

Comment: What is your complete/exact expected result from the input csv?  I don't know which column values you actually need to extract and which can be ignored.  It will also be helpful to see how you are storing the qualifying url for the next step in the process.

Comment: @mickmackusa the expected result is i save one entry as a product in my drupal site(node with fields for each entry). i use this URL to download product image and store it in my s3 bucket those functions I've already implemented.this i was struck at that moment.

Comment: I am specifically wondering if you actually need `Item ID`,`Brand Name`,`Manufacturer`, etc.  If you only need to extract the one qualifying value in each line, then there may be some argument for using regex.  If you need to extract more than one piece of data from each row, then processing each row of the data as an array probably makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your array, looking for Image Labels which are `PRODUCT IMAGE`, and then checking to see if the corresponding Image Info Label is `Marketing Image High Res`. If so, we break the loop and output the matching Image URL value:

```
for ($i = 1; ; $i++) {
    if (!isset($input["Image Label #$i"])) break;
    if ($input["Image Label #$i"] == 'PRODUCT_IMAGE') {
        if ($input["Image_info Label #$i"] == 'Marketing Image High Res') break;
    }
}
if (isset($input["Image Label #$i"])) {
    echo $input["Image URL #$i"];
}
```

Output:

```
http://www.image1.jpg
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/GDKNq)

If you can't be guaranteed that the Image label numbers start with 1 and are sequential, another, more complex solution that will work in that situation is as follows:

Here's one way of doing what you want. We use `array_keys` to find all the elements which have `PRODUCT_IMAGE` as their value, and then `array_map` to strip everything but the number from those values. In this case, we get the array `[1, 2, 3]`. We then do the same process for `Marketing Image High Res`, yielding `[1, 3]`. We then take the minimum of the intersection of the two arrays, which is the lowest image which is both `PRODUCT_IMAGE` and `Marketing Image High Res`, in this case `1`. Finally we echo out the appropriate URL by combining that value with `'Image URL #'`:

```
$product_images = array_map(function ($v) { return preg_replace('/^.*#/', '', $v); }, array_keys($input, 'PRODUCT_IMAGE'));
$highres_images = array_map(function ($v) { return preg_replace('/^.*#/', '', $v); }, array_keys($input, 'Marketing Image High Res'));
$min_key = min(array_intersect($product_images, $highres_images));
echo $input["Image URL #$min_key"];
```

Output:

```
http://www.image1.jpg
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uGco2)

Comment: @mickmackusa the old "corrected the code on the demo but forgot to copy it back to the answer" trick. That's twice this week!

Comment: i tried your previous one it worked. but regarding mick's comment it may affect.anyway i'll try with your updated solution too

Comment: @Rosh_LK I've incorporated that answer into this one just in case the simple loop won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all keys and search for the first occurence of `PRODUCT_IMAGE` as value. Then use `preg_match` to get the Id named in the key to get the corresponding url field:

```php
$image = null;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $match = null;
    if (preg_match('/^Image Label #(\d+)$/', $key, $match) && $value === 'PRODUCT_IMAGE') {
        $image = $array['Image URL ' . $match[1]];
        break;
    }
}
echo $image;
```